# Reading large Text file In VB.NET [Fragment the file into small files]

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, vb.net-2010

I'm facing a problems in reading a larger text file in vb.net
the file size is 2GB+

I'm wondering if I Fragmented the file into a small files [ each file 1 mb ]
and read each file individually would works

Please help me how to fragment the file into small files

I'm using vb.net .NET4

Comment: Do you actually have a text file which its size is more than 2GB? What's inside? Maybe the complete sequence of human genome?

Comment: haha, it's a list of strings need to be processed
I Need to read it line-by-line

Comment: so... presumably you've tried searching for "read text file line by line in vb.net" ?

Comment: file size is 2GB+. You can't use ReadLines

Comment: Have you thought about using streamreader?

Comment: It throw exception [out of memory]
I think the StreamBuffer is good but i don't know how to use it

Answer (score 1):

How did you read the large text file? Using IO.File.ReadAllLines() method? ReadAllLines needs to be completed before you can use the result. If your files is large, it takes time to completely read it.

Try IO.File.ReadLines() instead.

```
For Each line As String In IO.File.ReadLines("file.txt")
    Console.WriteLine(line)
Next
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx